# Hyperthreading enabled in BIOS, but not working under Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, xubuntu

I am running a standard Ubuntu 18.04.

```
$lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:security-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

But I am lacking hyperthreading.... It's 100% enabled in the BIOS. I disabled and enabled it just to check whether the problem was there, but it's not... However cpuinfo says: core : 4, siblings : 4, while it should be siblings : 8...

https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/88196/intel-core-i7-6700-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-00-ghz.html

I don't remember when this happened in my desktop... maybe since the upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04.

I am pasting the `lscpu`.

```
$lscpu 
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               94
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz
Stepping:            3
CPU MHz:             800.001
CPU max MHz:         4000.0000
CPU min MHz:         800.0000
BogoMIPS:            6816.00
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-3
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d
```

I tried to disable secure boot with `mokutil`, as suggested, and I got

```
$sudo mokutil --disable-validation
EFI variables are not supported on this system
```

So I checked the installation with `lsblk`

```
$lsblk 
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk  
├─sda1    8:1    0   487M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2    8:2    0     5M  0 part  
├─sda3    8:3    0  46.6G  0 part  /
└─sda4    8:4    0  72.2G  0 part  
sdb       8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sdb1    8:17   0   9.3G  0 part  [SWAP]
├─sdb2    8:18   0   7.2G  0 part  /var
├─sdb3    8:19   0  18.6G  0 part  /tmp
└─sdb4    8:20   0 896.4G  0 part  
  └─md0   9:0    0 896.2G  0 raid1 /home
sdc       8:32   0 931.5G  0 disk  
└─sdc1    8:33   0 896.4G  0 part  
  └─md0   9:0    0 896.2G  0 raid1 /home
```

So now, I am more than stuck... Any suggestion is welcome, thanks,

Alessandro

Comment: What is the output of `lscpu`?

Comment: I pasted the output of `lscpu` in the question. Thanks :-)

Comment: This is weird, `Thread(s) per core:  1` says that whether thread is not enabled or your CPU does not support threading, which is illogical according to Intel [website](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/88196/intel-core-i7-6700-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-00-ghz.html). 
Are you shure you enabled the threading from the BIOS menu? if yes, try to disable secure boot from the BIOS menu and check it again.

Comment: In the bios the hyperthreading is enabled 1000%. I would say that at also secure boot is disabled, otherwhise it would not have been possible to install several packages (e.g. virtualbox). As soon as I reboot the pc I'll double check. Thanks!

Comment: Also check this [discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/a24sfx/reenable_hyperthreading/) in Reddit, it may be useful.

Comment: Just to make sure, run this command `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/smt/active` if the output is 1, then Simultaneous MultiThreading is enabled, if 0 then it is disabled.
To enable it: `echo on > /sys/devices/system/cpu/smt/control`. Run it and then check again if the sibling numbers has changed

Comment: Thanks for the support. 
1. I checked and the secure boot is enabled... I had not the chance to disable it (I need also to check how to do it). I'll do it on Monday.
2. from ssh as SU I tried you commands: 
`# cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/smt/active
0
# echo on > /sys/devices/system/cpu/smt/control
bash: echo: write error: No such device`

Comment: The error you got means that, for your operating system, Hyperthreading is whether not enabled or it is not supported by the hardware (**which is absurd, since it is supported by the processor and enabled from the BIOS!**). Try disabling secure boot, if the problem persists, then it may be a hardware issue.

Comment: Thanks. So it looks that secure boot is disabled in the BIOS, although I can't have it to work in ubuntu using mokutil... I updated the question accordingly... I don't think it's a hardware issue, but more an installation "issue". Thanks!

Comment: @Alex were you able to enable this?

Answer (score -1):

You must disable secure boot in EFI BIOS.